# How do I create external Hive Table based on existing Orc file?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, external, orc

I have some orc files produced by spark job.
Is there some easy way to create an external table directly from those files?

Comment: Please go through this thorough tutorial https://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/using-hive-with-orc-from-apache-spark/ . Even though the tutorial is from HortonWorks, it works for the hadoop eco system in general.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done this is to first register a temp table in Spark job itself and then leverage the sql method of the HiveContext to create a new table in hive using the data from the temp table. For example if I have a dataframe df and HiveContext hc the general process is:

```
df.registerTempTable("my_temp_table")
hc.sql("CREATE TABLE new_table_name STORED AS ORC  AS SELECT * from my_temp_table")
```

Comment: This copies the ORC files to Hive warehouse.

Comment: @emeth Yes you are correct           and also create Hive table over the ORC file.